# 2.3 how can i upload SVG

Tags: magento2.3, svg

I used others post but not working, My currently problem is that I cannot seem.

how can i upload and use `SVG` file in magento `2.3`? please help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you want to use SVG images in **cms** pages.

*For the quick solution*  got to

> [your magento dir]\vendor\magento\module-cms\etc\di.xml

There you can see `<type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage">`
add **svg** to the list like this

```
<argument name="extensions" xsi:type="array">
<item name="allowed" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">image/jpg</item>
    <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">image/jpeg</item>
    <item name="png" xsi:type="string">image/png</item>
    <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">image/gif</item>
    <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">image/svg</item>
</item>
<item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">image/jpg</item>
    <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">image/jpeg</item>
    <item name="png" xsi:type="string">image/png</item>
    <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">image/gif</item>
    <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">image/svg</item>
</item>
<item name="media_allowed" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="flv" xsi:type="string">video/x-flv</item>
    <item name="swf" xsi:type="string">application/x-shockwave-flash</item>
    <item name="avi" xsi:type="string">video/x-msvideo</item>
    <item name="mov" xsi:type="string">video/x-sgi-movie</item>
    <item name="rm" xsi:type="string">application/vnd.rn-realmedia</item>
    <item name="wmv" xsi:type="string">video/x-ms-wmv</item>
</item>
```

Hope this helps.

**Please note that editing core files are not recommended. Please write it in your custom module.**

Don't forget to clear cache

Comment: not working on 2.3 `Attention, We don't recognize or support this file extension type.`

Comment: Did you cleared cache ?

Comment: I will check it in my local machine and update you

Comment: YES, i did, but not working

Comment: Hi @niceonelee i got solution. Use <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">image/svg+xml</item> instead of  <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">image/svg</item>

Comment: You will get error as "Unsupported image format. File" but able to append the svg image in cms-page. I am trying to solve the error.
Don't forget to clear cache and static content deployment.
I hope the above solution will solve for problem and i am looking for solutions to eliminate the error too.

Comment: @niceonelee I made a video in screencast https://www.screencast.com/t/cFVftfpLvi

Comment: yes but getting this error `header_logo_src does not contain field 'file'` cant upload into logo @

Comment: how to for logo and product image?thank you

Answer (score 1):

Working fine with M2.3:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="extensions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="allowed" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">text/plain</item>
                </item>
                <item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">text/plain</item>
                </item>
                <item name="media_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">text/plain</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**[Update]**

If this not still not working for you, You can debug what mime type is pass for this.

**vendor/magento/framework/File/Uploader.php**

```
/**
 * Used to check if uploaded file mime type is valid or not
 *
 * @param string[] $validTypes
 * @access public
 * @return bool
 */
public function checkMimeType($validTypes = [])
{
    error_log($this->_getMimeType());
    if (count($validTypes) > 0) {
        if (!in_array($this->_getMimeType(), $validTypes)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This **error_log($this->_getMimeType());** is actual mimetype. Add this type instead **text/plain**. Mime Type **text/plain** is for Magento default logo that is use by luma theme.

Comment: may i know where is /SR/MagentoCommunity?vendor/magento ? thank you

Comment: You can replace with your own module, in that case your module should load after Magento_Cms module.

Comment: showing this `File validation failed.`, i added in `vendor/magento/module-cms/etc/di.xml`

Comment: Check updated answer, check your svg file mime type.

Comment: i added 3 <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">text/plain</item> and error_log($this->_getMimeType()); code , but not work still, can we chat? thank you

Comment: have not showing too

Answer (score 1):

For Magento 2.3, You have to add this to di.xml of your custom module

```
<type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="extensions" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="allowed" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">image/svg+xml</item>
            </item>
            <item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">image/svg+xml</item>
            </item>
            <item name="media_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">image/svg+xml</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```