# can I use ```<svg> <path></svg> </path>``` instead of logo picture in magento2?

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

I'm trying to find a way that I want to use  `<svg> <path>content</svg> </path>` instead of logo picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to hardcode this in the template or use CSS as Magento does not support the uploading of SVG files as it's technically code and can be a vulnerability.

Or create a module and add the changes suggested on [2.3 how can i upload SVG](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263967/2-3-how-can-i-upload-svg)

Comment: could you please tell me the template directory ?

Comment: Magento_Theme::html/header/logo.phtml